# Java extensive Strategy Pattern - which way

Tags: java

I have three basic classes like `Base`, `Base2`, `Base3`. I have to create three encoders (`Encoder1`, `Encoder2`, `Encoder3`) which will encode it. In future I may add more encoders and base classes. Every bond of `Base` and `Encoder` will be unique and different from each other. I would like to find best oop pattern which will be the most flexible and elegant. I read about Strategy pattern. It is great in case when I have one `Base` class and many `Encoder` classes. I will create it like this

```
AbstractEncoder
-Encoder1
-Encoder2
-EncoderN
```

and pass it as parameter in constructor in `Base` class. But in this example I have many-to-many relation. Should I modify Strategy pattern under my needs? I have only one idea...

```
AbstractEncoder
-AbstractBase1
 -Base1Encoder1
 -Base2Encoder2
-AbstractBase2
 -Base2Encoder1
 -Base2Encoder2
...
```

but it's quite "exploding". Does anyone have any idea how to do it better?

Comment: By writing code

Comment: I don't understand your many to many relations. Could you try to define your need in a more specific way? It is not very clear.

Comment: What do you mean with `Base` and `Encoder`? Can't you find a good analogy? Why do you want to make `Base`, which seems to be a model class, dependent from `Encoder`, which seems to contain logic (e.g. _pass it as parameter in constructor in Base class_) ? It should be the other way around if there is a direct dependency between these two. In general, what are similarities/differences between Base1, 2 and 3? What for Encoder1,2 and 3? The easiest way would be to have a `Consumable` interface for `Base`s and a `Consuming<B extends Consumable>` interface for `Encoder`s.

Comment: `Base1Encoder1`, `Base2Encoder2` and so one aren't classes. They are instances: `base1Encoder2 = new Encoder2(new Base1())`

Comment: From what I see here I'd point to Visitor pattern. But that's really a wild guess, as what you describe here is a fragment of a solution, and ask how to complete it. But that's pretty hard without any hint what's to b solved, isn't it? So maybe adding some detail about the desired outcome would help to get a qualified answer.